# Collapsing elements responsively in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way in Bootstrap where I can set at which screen size an element is collapsed or not collapsed like how it's done for hidden and show?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some classes to the div that you want to hide/show only on certain screen sizes, you can check for the classes: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities